# unusable profiles no private Certificate found on corona simulator

Tags: coronasdk, profile, provisioning

I have added Provisioning Profile on Keys Mac and Apple developer but Corona Simulator complains for

> unusable profiles no private Certificate found

How can i add Provisioning Profile on Corona Simulator

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Corona adds all the certificates automatically from your Xcode. 
Go to this window on your Xcode to see if they are there:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BujCQ.png

If the issue is ok above, you possibly have an outdated Corona version, try using the last public release.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed password for your Apple Developer account. You need to reset your certificates, regenerate your provision profiles, download them and restart Corona simulator.